# How to update PHP and MySQL in SUSE LINUX Release 11.2

Tags: php, mysql, linux, opensuse, suse

I have in a server SUSE LINUX Release 11.2, with PHP Version 5.2.17 and phpMyAdmin  3.3.9, How can I do for update the two elements, I tried with:

```
sudo apt-get update php5
```

but dont works, says:

```
 sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

I think this is only for Ubuntu, I has been searching for the correct comands without successful.

One question, in the update I will lost the prev config?

Hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Yast already?

Comment: You can also build your php manually after download with configure, make, make install.